# How to get source code of page with out runing firefox by using selenium?

Tags: html, selenium-webdriver

I want create web crawler that save links of pages .And I wrote this code in win app and worked currently . Now I want done this work with out opening browser.Please help

```
using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using OpenQA.Selenium;
    using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
    namespace spammer
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private IWebDriver driver;
            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                driver = new FirefoxDriver();
                driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://blogfa.com/members/UsersList.aspx?dir=01");
                IList<IWebElement> lis = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector(".ull > li > a"));
                string href = null;
                foreach (IWebElement li in lis)
                {
                     href += li.GetAttribute("href")+ " ";
                }


            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you don't want to open a browser you can use `headless mode`

Comment: How to do this? Can you write  sample code?

Comment: try `driver = new HtmlUnitDriver()`

Comment: I do this But get error for me : cannot resolve symbol 'HtmlUnitDriver' . I use resharper If this require  name space ,  get me suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Headless browser helps you because headless browser is a browser without GUI. Webdriver mainly supports 2 headless browsers :

1. HTMLUnit -- Following line of code will help you.

import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;

```
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
        driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(capabilities);
```

2. PhantomJS -- Following line of code will help you.

   Download phantonJS driver and use the following line of code.

   ```
       DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
       capabilities.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
       capabilities.setCapability("takesScreenshot", true);
       capabilities.setCapability(
               "PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY",
               "<Path of phantomJS driver>"
           );


       driver = new PhantomJSDriver(capabilities);
   ```

Note : I recommended to use PhantomJS as it gives more accurate result compare to HTMLUnit.

Answer (score 0):

WebDriver has a built-in method to get the pagesource being driver().getPageSource();

Another way is to use xpath: driver.getElementByXpath("body");